# Passing data to post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, razor, get, actionmethod

I have a view model that looks like this

```
 public class ViewModelRound2 
    {
        public Bid Bid { get; set; }
        public bool SelectedForRound2 { get; set; }  
    }
```

I have a get action method that looks like this

```
public ActionResult Round2Manager(long id)
        {
            ...

            return View(round1Ring3Bids);
        }
```

And a post method that looks like this (not implemented it yet)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Round2Manager(IEnumerable<ViewModelRound2> viewModelRound2)
        {
            return View(viewModelRound2);
        }
```

My view looks like this

```
   @for (var x = 0; x < Model.Count(); x++)
    {
        ViewModelRound2 viewModelRound2 = Model.ElementAt(x);
        Bid bid = viewModelRound2.Bid;

        string userName = @bid.User.Invitation.Where(i => i.AuctionId == bid.Lot.Lot_Auction_ID).First().User.User_Username;

        <tr>
            <td>
                @userName
            </td>
            <td>
                @bid.Bid_Value
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(c => c.ElementAt(x).SelectedForRound2) 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div class="buttonwrapper2">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Round2Manager", new { viewModelRound2 = Model }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST"} )
</div>
```

The page this renders, contains checkboxes per row in the rendered table and I want to be able to pass checked/unchecked values to the post method so that it can process them.  The problem is that the `viewModelRound2` parameter of the post method is always null.  What is going on?  How can I write this so that it does what I intend?

Comment: Does this snippet lies inside a form...?

Comment: Yes, it should, I wrote that as answer... Didn't want to do that unless I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all that HTML inside a `<form>`.

Comment: @SachinKainth. You should use `ajaxForm`, and not `ajaxlink`.

Comment: by the way I don't need to use ajax.

Comment: @SachinKainth. Then you should know what you're doing, because you do use `AJAX`... Just add `<input type="submit" value="submit"` to the form.

Comment: I changed the post method to what it is in my post because I realised that's what I needed and made the changes you suggested and now viewModelRound2 is not null but it does always contain 0 elements.